# Which port to open on a server for Google Maps geocode queries?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, server, port, dmz

I have a program that queries google maps service via javascript for geocodes. I need to run that program on a server. I don't know which ports need to be opened to access the google maps URL. The URL that I'm using to access the maps code is:

- http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js

This URL returns a javascript file which has a piece of code that looks like this:

```
  var loadScriptTime = (new Date).getTime();
  getScript("http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/10/main.js");
```

I know that these are HTTP request and that port 80 needs to be opened but as the server is in DMZ, I don't think I can ask the client to open port 80 as that would necessarily enable all the HTTP requests.

Is there a proper list of URLs that I can allow through the firewall so that my program runs? (obviously besides the above two URLs that I mentioned)

Comment: So is there any solution for this particular problem? @PatrickEvans

Comment: Port 80 isnt usually blocked by firewalls, for outgoing requests, since that is the normal http port, I believe the same goes for https port. What is the actual problem that you are having? Is the server not able to get the script file?

Comment: I think the firewall is blocking any outgoing requests. So I need to allow a list of google maps api URLs through the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some URLs that I found are required for the GMaps to download the scripts and other resources:

1. maps.google.com
2. maps.gstatic.com
3. apis.google.com